# What does '60D' mean in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What does the `60D` mean in below Scala line? Is it `60` in decimal number? I need to convert the code into equivalent snowflake query for migration activity.

```
((col("date_1").cast("long")-col("date_2").cast("long"))/60D)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the value `60` expressed as a `Double`, usually written as `60.0`.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala if you divide integer by integer you will get an integer.

```
12 / 5 == 2
```

This is similar to Spark (I see you probably rewrite some Spark job?). If you want to get a double value instead you have to make sure at least one value is a double. There are many options including

```
12 / 5.0 == 2.4
12 / 5D == 2.4
```

It is probably not relevant to you anyways as you are not producing any Scala code there.